# Laravel - Как вытащить с таблицы данные, которых нет в другой таблице?

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы:

- table_1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 |
| 2 | name_2 |

- table_2

| id | another_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | name_1 |
| 2 | 2 | name_3 |
| 3 | 1 | name_2 |
| 4 | 3 | name_4 |

Нужно вытащить `name` из таблицы `table_1`, которых нет в `table_2` и чтобы не совпадало c полем `another_id`.

```php
return DB::table('table_1')
    ->leftJoin('table_2', 'table_1.name' , '=' , 'table_2.name')
    ->where('table_2.name', null) ->where('table_2. another_id' ,'!= ', $id)
    ->select('table_1.name' )
    ->get();
```

Сделал так. Если убрать условие `where('table_2. another_id' ,'!= ', $id)`, то срабатывает, но мне нужно чтобы ещё сравнивалось с полем `another_id` с `$id` который я передаю.

Comment: `table_2. another_id` - тут пробел. Не в этом дело?

Comment: нет, не в пробеле проблема

Comment: Покажите какой запрос получается. `DB::enableQueryLog();
        /** ваш код */
        dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: Я думаю `->where('table_2. another_id' ,'!= ', $id)` нужно вытащить в left join. Вот пример с рабочего проекта `->leftJoin("bet AS bet_win", function ($join) use ($companyId) {
    $join->on('bet_win.id', '=', "tender.bet_winner_id");
    $join->on('bet_win.company_id', '=', $companyId);
})`

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `table_1`.`name` from `table_1` left join `table_2` on `table_1`.`name` = `table_2`.`name` where `table_2`.`name` is null and `table_2`.`any_id` = ?"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "!= "
    ]
    "time" => 0.21
  ]
]  dd(DB::getQueryLog());

Comment: Сделал по вашему примеру, вылетает ошибка, ругается на id который я передаю SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `table_1`.`name` from `table_1` left join `table_2` on `table_1`.`name` = `table_2`.`name` and `table_2`.`any_id` != `1` where `table_2`.`name` is null)